# AngularJS reducing HTTP request by combining javascript files

Tags: javascript, http, angularjs, gruntjs, bundling-and-minification

Using angularJS is great. Although i see a problem in that i have the following files:

- app.js
- controllers.js
- filters.js
- directives.js
- services.js

That along with the actually AngularJS library files and perhaps jQuery is allot of http requests to the server.

Is there a way to combine all these together for a production environment? More to the point is there a specific AngularJS recommended way to do this?

Comment: What are you using for server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Grunt.js project is able to execute tasked commands such as minification and concatenation as I described above. The two grunt.js plugins with the widest support for these tasks are:

- Uglify (minification)
- Concat (file concatenation)

below is a sample task script for these:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
      options: {
        separator: ';'
      },
      dist: {
        src: ['assets/**/*.js'],
        dest: 'assets/js/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      options: {
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy") %> */\n'
      },
      dist: {
        files: {
          'assets/js/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js': ['<%= concat.dist.dest %>']
        }
      }
    },
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'uglify']);

};
```

I dont usually answer my onw questions although i believe that relying on a server to compile, cache and check cached versions is not the way to go. Unnecessary processors and systems to maintain on a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Combining and minification of script is mostly done on server. Different technologies\tools provide different mechanism to support this feature. I dont think it is a AngularJS concern.

The only thing you need to take care if using minification is dependency injection can break in Angular. So this form of DI would be preferred.

```
app.controller('myController',['dependency1',
    function(dependency1) {
    }
]);
```

Comment: yeah im aware that this is outside the domain of AngularJS. Although im looking for suggestions on how to carry out this task. I would like to steer away from server side asset compilation / minification and more towards production compilation / minification.

Comment: What is the difference between server side and production compilation?

Comment: If you are thinking that the server has to process the files to generate the minified version, then that is not the case. The minification on the server happens one time (using some tool) and is not done with each request. So actual server processing is not affected.

Comment: Yes. But simple to reduce systems that i have to maintain, i would prefer to have a build script that is executed prior to pulling changes into a production branch. I understand that there are ways to setup an automatic build with caching. I have since discovered grunt.js